# Is it possible that after launching new activity the previous activity keeps sending data to new activity via intent?

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app in which i'm sending data to another activity via intent . is it possible that after launch of new activity data transfer (updates) continue to receive by new activity? links would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a background service for this. Once an activity is not in view, it could be in pause state or even on destroy state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If another activity is loaded, then the previous one goes on the onPause state.
It wouldn't be accurate expecting anything from a paused activity.

Depending on the case and the function of the second activity, you could either use a service, or depending on your case, you might also be able to use fragments and stick with one activity.

An example of your code would be helpful to understand the case.